# French Characters in CSV

Tags: c#, html, csv

I have an situation! I have a string which contains French characters in html format like "o" also "téléphone" but when i export these through c# code in the CSV file then it looks something like this as follows
o => & lt;sup& gt;o& lt;/sup& gt;
téléphone => t& #233;l& #233;phone

I wanted to show these words in the same format as which is seen on HTML page.

Is there any way to do this? Let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is HTML that you want to convert to text, you need to HTML Decode the strings before exporting.

[`HttpUtitlity.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d4sx29z.aspx) will do the trick.